# BahaviorSubject converted to Observable is not recognized as such

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have problems converting a BehaviorSubject of a boolean value to a 'correct' observable.
  **Background:**
I have a method toValue() that takes different types and converts them to a uniform format. Observables should also be recognized and typed as such, which works so far.

To react to a changing boolean value, I have implemented @pashozator's response under the following [reddit-link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/76inse/noob_observable_on_change_of_value/). Thus I pass to my toValue() method a 
BehaviorSubject.asObservable(), which looks something like this:

```
private isFinished: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

toValue(this.isFinished.asObservable());

this.isFinished.next(true);
```

in the toValue() method the converted BehaviorSubject is not recognized as Observable, BehaviorSubject or Subject, so I cannot type it as Observable.

The only difference between the "real" Observable and the one from the BehaviorSubject is that the `source` attribute is not `Observable`, but `BehaviorSubject`.

```
// inside toValue()
//...

console.log(param instanceof Observable);      // false for isFinished.asObservable()
console.log(param instanceof BehaviorSubject); // false for isFinished.asObservable()
console.log(param instanceof Subject);         // false for isFinished.asObservable()

if (param instanceof Observable) {
    observable = (param as Observable<T>);
}

// ...
```

**Why is the converted BehaviorSubject not recognized as Observable and how is it possible to recognize and treat the converted BehaviorSubject as Observable?
The aim should be that both cases ("real" and converted Observable) are treated immediately and can be subscribed to later.**

---

**EDIT:**

Here is working plunkr, the code is inside the init function of the app.component

https://plnkr.co/edit/MDxGS5kNgYNJaPmOaGXe?p=info

Comment: The `ngOnInit` function is empty in your plnkr

Comment: @martin fixed that

Comment: `asObservable` is a method so you have to use it as `this.isFinished.asObservable()`

Comment: @martin same result as before, was just a typo in the example

Comment: console.log(param instanceof Observable); this logs true for me. You also have additional mistakes in the toValue function, param is misspelled in one place, and the observable variable is not defined before assignment.

Comment: @JohnDizzle I can see `true` for `param instanceof Observable`

Comment: I updated the code again but it only works in incognito mode for me...very strange

Comment: You probably have cache problems. Try to enable Disable cache in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asObservable` [returns `Observable` instance](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Subject.ts#L129), as the name suggest. It's an observable. `param instanceof Observable === false` suggests that it's it's not an observable at all (can be undefined), or `Observable` class isn't the same class as the class that was imported in this module.

There can be more than one copy of RxJS package in the project. This may be desirable thing or not. In this case de-duping `rxjs` package may help.

Any way, a cleaner way to check if it's an observable is to use an approach used in [`is-observable`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-observable/blob/master/index.js#L4) package. Considering that the application has ES6 polyfills including `Symbol`, there's no need for abstractions. It is:

```
if (param && param[Symbol.observable]) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to import rxjs library components. Make sure not to mix them up.

- Use import statements from inside rxjs internal (not recommended):

  *import {Subject} from 'rxjs/**internal**'*

  *import {takeUntil, map, tap} from 'rxjs/**internal**/operators'*
- Use import statements from the package directly (the more correct option):

  *import {Subject} from 'rxjs'*

  *import {takeUntil, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators'*

If you are receiving an error such as:

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can
> provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

There is a high chance you mixed the imports, as each refers to a different definition of types (e.g. Observable types are different)